# How to resolve the issue of flash video downloader in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, video-conversion

I am trying to download a vimeo video from a web page but the issue is that my flash video downloader works for some videos and for other videos ,it is disabled so how to resolve this,I have tried installing it again ,even tried updating my browser , but still not resolved.
I can't download it through IDM due to some internal issues, so please tell me how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it's related to this article:
[Chrome doesn't support NPAPI](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en)

As mentioned in that page, you can follow these steps:

> If Flash isn't working, try these solutions to fix the problem:
>
> **Step 1:** Turn on PPAPI plugins.
>
> 1. Open Chrome.
> 2. In the address bar at the top, type chrome://plugins and
>      press **Enter**.
> 3. Click Details. Scroll down to "Adobe Flash Player."
> 4. Under
>      "Type: PPAPI," click **Enable**.
>
> **Step 2:** Make sure Chrome is up-to-date.
>   You get Adobe Flash player on Chrome automatically, and it updates
>   when Chrome does.
>
> **Step 3:** Update Adobe Flash Player manually.
>
> 1. Open Chrome.
> 2. In the address bar at the top, type chrome://components
>      and press **Enter**.
> 3. Under "pepper_flash," click **Check for update**.

Comment: I tried it still it is not working , I had downloaded one vimeo downloader premium ,but its license expired after 3 days , so is there any way to delete its registry details so that I can still work with it .

Answer (score 0):

Download an older version of Chrome  as Java is no longer supported on newer versions of Chrome. Perhaps you can check chrome://flags amd enable NPAPI to see if that works.